# Heroku files written by the app are not visible in bash

Tags: bash, file, heroku

I published my first simple app on Heroku with a free dyno. This app writes a simple .txt file, that seems to be correctly written because my API services are working fine.
But if I try to check this file by entering in the file system using "heroku run bash -a MYAPP", I can't see that file in the folder I thought to see. It is like the file is not existing. Can someone tell me why?
Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem

Answer (score 2):

I found this on https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/active-storage-on-heroku:

> In addition, any files stored on disk will not be visible from one-off dynos such as a `heroku run bash` instance or a scheduler task because these commands use new dynos.

It is still not so clear to me, but at least I know it is a normal (but strange) behaviour of Heroku!

Comment: just ran into this weird issue, it creates csv files in my python app, but I could not find them anywhere from bash, yet the heroku app was using the newly created files.